# updated os to mojave 10.14.5, now lsof is giving me errors with stat

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, mojave

I had a system update last Thursday and ever since I have been getting the errors below. I have tried reinstalling lsof via homebrew, upgrading bash,
rebooting, but no luck. How do I even go about debugging this issue.

```
$ lsof -i
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() apfs file system /
      Output information may be incomplete.
      assuming "dev=1000004" from mount table
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() devfs file system /dev
      Output information may be incomplete.
      assuming "dev=396eef60" from mount table
lsof: too many (> 32) symbolic links in readlink() path: devfs
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() apfs file system /private/var/vm
      Output information may be incomplete.
      assuming "dev=1000006" from mount table
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() autofs file system /net
      Output information may be incomplete.
      assuming "dev=32000001" from mount table
lsof: too many (> 32) symbolic links in readlink() path: map -hosts
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() autofs file system /home
      Output information may be incomplete.
      assuming "dev=32000002" from mount table
```